# What can be done to rename two conflicting applications that have the same name?

Tags: macos, applications

Is there a way to rename an application? I like to use the desktop app from getpocket.com which is called Pocket. I would also like use the app from lastpass called Pocket. I can't use both with out overriding the other. Is there a way that these two apps can live in harmony?

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Do you launch them from spotlight? Does renaming them not work?

Comment: they are both named pocket.app. Last time I tried using both the overwrote each other. Before adding the new pocket.app I wanted some assurance that this time wouldn't break anything. Not quite sure if I can just rename them

Answer (score 2):

Since pocket for Mac comes from the Mac App Store, you might let that exist in /Applications. The other app from Lastpass might be better if you place it in a folder ~/Applications or perhaps /Applications/Lastpass so that you don't have a collision.